# Delete all traces of plugin in database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, plugins

I deleted a WordPress plugin to install an older version of that plugin but the new version continues to show on the front end.

Steps I have taken:

I deleted the plugin folder.

Searched the database for any tables left behind by the plugin. No tables.

Searched the plugins scripts to see how it connects to database. I searched for the terms $wpdb, set_option() and update_option(). I only found update_option() in this plugins scripts.

I found the following in different locations in this plugins folder:

update_option( $option_key, $savedOptions );

update_option( $this->tabs[ $tab_id ][ 'option_key' ], array() );

update_option( $option_key, $option_data );

update_option( 'xoo_'.$this->slug.'_theme_templates_data', $tempData );

update_option( 'xoo-ml-before-2', 'yes' );

update_option( $version_option, XOO_WSC_VERSION);

And this is where I am stuck... Does any of the above code store info in the database that would prevent me from getting the old version of the plugin back?

My research has me looking in the direction of _options table but I am not sure what to do their or if that is where I need to be...